# google gdk java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Card

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I created a simple glass app using the samples as an example. The app has an Activity that creates cards, adds them to a CardScrollView and sets the content to the scroll view.  I created a trigger to be used as an "ok glass" prompt to start the activity. I made sure I was using the Glass Development Kit Sneak Peek as the version of Android.  The app compiles and deploys to the Google Glass device but when it runs I get the following error.  Also the "ok glass" prompt does not display.  Not sure what version of the firmware is required but the Google Glass device indicates that it is currently at XE10 and that it is up to date.

```
12-03 12:36:02.125: E/dalvikvm(12040): Could not find class 'com.google.android.glass.app.Card', referenced from method com.android.graingerglass.CategoriesCardAdapter.<init>
12-03 12:36:02.125: E/dalvikvm(12040): Could not find class 'com.google.android.glass.app.Card', referenced from method com.android.graingerglass.CategoriesCardAdapter.getView
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.glass.app.Card
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040):    at com.android.graingerglass.CategoriesCardAdapter.<init>(CategoriesCardAdapter.java:27)
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040):    at com.android.graingerglass.CategoriesCardActivity$LoadCategories.onPostExecute(CategoriesCardActivity.java:45)
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040):    at com.android.graingerglass.CategoriesCardActivity$LoadCategories.onPostExecute(CategoriesCardActivity.java:1)
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-03 12:36:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(12040):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post Code.  Can't really help without it.

Comment: The other interesting thing is that when running the app the Google Glass device shows up as a 4.0.4 device. I was expecting 4.0.3

Answer (score 1):

XE10 is your problem. GDK Sneak Peek requires XE11.

You'll need to let your Glass OTA to XE11.